# HTML point-events filtering non-interactive elements?

Tags: html, css, canvas

I'm thinking about making a simple web game using the <canvas> API. I've looked around at JavaScript libraries for GUI elements rendered directly to the canvas and found some that look nice such as [Zebra](http://zebkit.org/), but I'd prefer to stick with the standard DOM controls rendered on top of the canvas. However, I'm running into problems with mouse input being trapped by the <div>s I'm using to contain the buttons, textboxes, and so on that I want to use.

Consider the following image, or go to [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GD4Da/17/) to see my code so far.

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [ekardnt.com](http://www.ekardnt.com/capture.PNG))</sub>

The red background is a canvas element, and the blue background is a div with four buttons. Both the canvas and the div have the "position: absolute" CSS properties. I have added simple alert() calls to the canvas' and div's onclick event, to show me what elements are capturing input.

What I want is for the canvas' onclick to be called whenever the click did not fall on a button. That is, if I click on the exposed blue background of the button container div, I want the click event to "fall through" to the canvas. Currently, however, the div's onclick is called both when I click a button and when I click in the blue area - a sensible default behavior, but inconvenient for me.

Is there a way to get the behavior I want? I've tried adding `pointer-events: none` to the div's style but then the buttons don't respond to input at all.

Comment: How about not using a div container for you buttons?  Instead, position:absolute the buttons over the canvas. If you want a blue background for your button group, draw a blue rect on the canvas.  My reasoning is that (as you've discovered) pointer-events has not yet been universally adopted by browsers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `pointer-events: none;` to the `#buttons` container, and `pointer-events:auto;` to the button elements. Then a click on the container will "fall-through", while the buttons remain functional.

http://jsfiddle.net/GD4Da/18/

```css
#buttons {
    /* ... */
    pointer-events: none;
}
#buttons button {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly on Firefox 24, does not work on IE 11 (the buttons don't respond to mouse input at all, suggesting the 'none' on the div overrides the 'auto' on the buttons). Is there a workaround for IE or should I just laugh at those users?

Comment: @Drake You could decide to not use `pointer-events` in IE11, and use JavaScript to retarget events on the canvas, using `var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');` `event.initMouseEvent( ... )` and `element.dispatchEvent(event);`.